# Not able to push after git rebase

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

I am new to git and i want to use the git rebase feature to merge my few commits. However After after I run the rebase command and merge the commits, I am not able to push the changes.

> On branch master Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and
>   have 1 and 2 different commits each, respectively.   (use "git pull"
>   to merge the remote branch into yours)
>
> nothing to commit, working directory clean

Following is the process I am following.

1. Following is the output of the **git log --pretty=oneline** command
   7014f2b4f01c40868f488b0cc28742d179b6c404 Third Commit
   64504dfab9f37250760a0862199e0291fc1bce6e Second Commit
   e4869ace429dc8f60ec1862bbfb19330eefbfe6a First Commit
2. Second command - **git rebase -i HEAD~2**

   **pick** 64504df Second Commit

   **squash** 7014f2b Third Commit

    I am getting following output after rebase is done, and after this not able to push changes.

   [detached HEAD 35b14b0] Second Commit
   1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
   Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master.

Output of git log --oneline --graph --decorate HEAD...@{u}

```
* 454f5f4 (HEAD, master) Second Commit 
* 7014f2b (origin/master) Third Commit 
* 64504df Second Commit
```

Please not that all the changes are also pushed to github as well.

Comment: Use `gitk HEAD...@{u}` to visualize what is going on. What is the output of `git log --online --graph --decorate HEAD...@{u}`?

Comment: following is the output of **git log --oneline --graph --decorate** HEAD...@{u}
* 454f5f4 (HEAD, master) Second Commit
* 7014f2b (origin/master) Third Commit
* 64504df Second Commit

Comment: There is no good formatting in comments. Please add formatted output like that of `git log` directly to you question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you already pushed your two changes to origin.

Now the rebase throws away the last two commits and replaces them by a single combined commit.

Therefore the branches "diverted". The remote repository contains two commits where your local repository contains a single commit. Normally you are only able to push if you are only adding new commits. Therefore git complains.

General rule: **Never** rebase commits you already pushed.

If you simply want to push your changes use `git pull` or `git pull --rebase`. This will merge or rebase you local changes on top of the remote changes. Afterwards you should be able to push without problems.

Comment: #michas, you are right my all the three branches are pushed to github. Is there any way I can can merge commits on github. or this rebase is for local commits only.

Comment: Added pull part to the answer.